# How to cut video and add overlay at the same time?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am currently cutting a video and after it is cut I am adding an layer of text like this:

```
$cut_video_cmd = 'ffmpeg -i "'.$video_path.'" -vf scale=640:-1 -ss 30 -t 10 "'.$video_path.'"';

$add_text_to_video_cmd = 'ffmpeg -i "'.$video_path.'" -vf drawtext="fontfile='.public_path('assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf').': \
    text=\'Stack Overflow\': fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5: \
    boxborderw=5: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2" -codec:a copy "'.$video_path.'.overlay.mp4"';
```

It works great, but I am wondering if there is a way to combine these two commands? Or any way to simplify this process? I am failing to figure this out.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chain linear filters with a comma. Simplified example of your command:

```
ffmpeg -i input -ss 30 -t 10 -vf scale=640:-2,drawtext -codec:a copy output
```